# How can I use Python dependency injection by querying a unique tag (use annotation to register a specific class first)

Tags: python

I am a new user of Python annotation. I am trying to achieve dependency by annotation.

```
class Trie():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = self.Node()
        self.count = 0

    class Node():
        def __init__(self, value=None):
            self.value = value
            self.children = {}

    def add(self, key, value):
        path = key.split('.')
        node = self.root
        for token in path:
            if token not in node.children:
                node.children[token] = self.Node()
            node = node.children[token]
        node.value = value
        self.count += 1

    def get(self, key, default_value=None):
        path = key.split('.')
        node = self.root
        for token in path:
            if token not in node.children:
                return default_value
            node = node.children[token]
        self.count -= 1
        return node.value


_REGISTRY = Trie()


def register_cls(identifier):
    def add_class(cls):
        _REGISTRY.add(identifier, cls)
        return cls

    return add_class


def find_cls(identifier, default_value=None):
    return _REGISTRY.get(identifier, default_value)
```

This is the code to register the class and find the class by class name.
**But I do not know how to register a class from another file.**

```
@register_cls('resnet18')
class ResNet18:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'resnet18'

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name_18 = 'resnet18'
    model = find_cls(name_18)
    print(model().get_name())
    assert model().get_name() == name_18
```

I can only use this function as this test. `find_cls()` and `@register_cls()` in the same file. But this code can store the path of the file, how can I use this function to read the class cross different files.

Comment: Are you asking how to import the `find_cls` and `register_cls` functions in another module (.py file)?

Comment: No, I know how to import find_cls and register_cls.

Comment: I do not know how to use find_cls to find a class that is "@register_cls" in another.py file

Comment: I want to implement that:`register.py: @register_cls('resnet') Class Resnet: .....` and `find_class.py: find_cls('resnet')`